# Как сравнить массивы на наличие элементов одного массива в другом и если есть совпадение, убрать элементы первого из второго?

Tags: c, массивы, строки

В общем задание такое, что нужно прочитать файл (в котором код другой программы), и все for убрать, а если в какой-то строке есть **printf/scanf**, то вывести какая это строка. Попытался что-то погуглить, нашёл только **strcmp** и **strcpy**, но strcmp сравнивает полностью и поэтому не годится, если выводить строки. Думал поэлементно читать и написать что-то типа **if(str[i] == 'f' && str[i+1] == 'o' && str[i+2]**, но выводить посимвольно у меня не получается.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* file = fopen("text.txt", "r+");

    if ((file = fopen("text.txt", "r+")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open the file\n");
    }
    else
    {
        char str1[] = "for";
        char str[100];

        printf("File was successfully opened\n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            fgets(str, 100, file);
            printf("%s", str);


            if (strcmp(str, str1))
            {
                strcpy(str, " ");
                printf("%s", str);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Название темы **никак** не связано с тем, что написано в теле. Так о чём всё-таки речь?

Comment: Есть еще такая хорошая функция, как `strstr`...

Answer (score 0):

В общем виде алгоритм выглядит следующим образом:
Цикл с вторым массивом находится анутри цикла с первым
1. Берётся элемент от первого массива и сравнивается со всеми из второго
2. Если элемент есть во втором массиве, добавим его в новый(в котором хранятся дубликаты), так найдём все элементы во втором, которые есть в первом.
3. Пройдёмся циклом через дубликаты и удалим их из второго.

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* file = fopen("test.c", "rt");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open the file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("File was successfully opened\n\n");

    int lineno = 0;
    char str[1024];

    while(fgets(str, 1024, file))
    {
        ++lineno;
        if (strstr(str,"printf") || strstr(str,"scanf"))
            printf(">>>> printf/scanf in line #%d\n", lineno);

        char * fnd;

        while(fnd = strstr(str,"for"))
            memmove(fnd,fnd+3,strlen(fnd+3)+1);

        printf("%s", str);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Назовите файл `test.c`, скомпилируйте и посмотрите на вывод :)